# How to run a file before setup with Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Is it possible to run a file with Inno Setup, before the setup beginns?
[Documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes it is. In the `[code]` section run the file in the `InitializeSetup()` function. This example launches notepad before the setup runs.

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): boolean;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin

  // Launch Notepad and wait for it to terminate
  if Exec(ExpandConstant('{win}\notepad.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
  end
  else begin
    // handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code
  end;

  // Proceed Setup
  Result := True;

end;
```

Comment: This should not be done in InitializeSetup if it changes anything on the users computer. This should be done after the user has pressed "Install", i.e. PrepareToInstall() or CurStepChanged(ssInstall).

Answer (score 1):

```
[Code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
   ResultCode: integer;
begin
   ExtractTemporaryFile('卸载.bat');
   if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\卸载.bat'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
   end
   else begin
   end;
   
end;
```

[detail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6M0c.png)

Comment: If you want to run the bat file in the exe when you click next, the above code is perfect

Comment: You can actually run the BAT file