# Execute a batch file before [Files] section in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Currently my batch file is in `[Run]` section. I need my batch file to execute before the `[Files]` section. Is there a way to do this in Inno Setup? Currently the `[Run]` section always execute after `[Files]` section.

```
[Run]
Filename: "C:\Users\Scripts\Install\Install.bat"; \
    Parameters: {code:GetDatabaseName}  

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\MyApp\*"; DestDir: "\\MyServer\MyApp"; \
    Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it needs to be done at the beginning of the setup, use `Exec()` in the `PrepareToInstall()` or `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)` event functions.
These are both after the user has said "go ahead, install" but before anything else.
`PrepareToInstall()` also allows you to cancel the install with a nice warning.

If the file needs to be extracted from the setup first, then you can preceed it with `ExtractTemporaryFile()`

Answer (score 7):

Continuing Deanna's great answer, code example:

```
[code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
   ResultCode: integer;
begin
   Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\serviceDeployment\unInstallService.bat'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
end;
```

this code always returns an empty string, which tells the setup to continue.
In case you want to stop setup (in some error cases) you need to return a non empty string and it will be displayed to the user (and setup will be stopped).

In order to return an error string add this line in PrepareToInstall's:

```
Result := 'Your Error Description';
```

Comment: Well, then would be fair to show how to handle error when `Exec` fails, or when the executed target returns an error (in this case a batch script returning certain `ERRORLEVEL`).

Comment: Exec is boolean. so you can check whether it true or false.
and ResultCode contains the error code.
  
     if not Exec(.........) then
        begin
            Result := 'Your Error Description';
         end

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `InitializeSetup` event + some pascal scripting.

See; [How to run a file before setup with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493416/how-to-run-a-file-before-setup-with-inno-setup)

Not mentioned in that example; to get the file from the installer you would use `ExtractTemporaryFile('your.bat')` then `Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\your.bat ...` to run it.

Comment: I needed it after the setup since I will need to grab user input value.